# Power BI: How to merge two tables (loaded plus created table)

Tags: powerbi

I'm struggling with what I assume is a calculated table in Power BI Desktop.
I need to somehow connect my database loaded Accounts table with a manually created Progress table (with some fixed data), so that each row in Accounts basically has a calculated column which is the resulting Progress table for that row. (Hope that makes sense).

[This is the Progress table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8eM.png)
The calculated columns in the Progress table should use data from the related Accounts row to give an overview of where the Account is now, how long it took and the likely future time frames to reach the next levels of progress.

Is there a way to do such a thing?
TIA!
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Add a column in the model layer using the DAX LOOKUPVALUE function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx
2. From the Edit Queries window, use the Merge Queries button, then Expand the resulting NewColumn.

Comment: I ended up creating a copy (calculated) of the Accounts table and then adding each step as a calculated column with a different name. some 136 columns in all. An awful solution, but at least it works. The Merge Queries option didn't work as that seems to demand that both tables have the same columns and a common row identifier. Lookup could have been an idea, didn't think of that, but it probably wouldn't have been any prettier. What I was really hoping for was more of a parent-child relationship so that each row of Accounts could have several rows of "Progress".

Comment: I might redesign the database instead so that when an Account row is inserted, the Progress rows are added by code. Then the Progress table could get the AccountID and everything should be easier. Still, I'm very impressed by PowerBI so far, and if I do come up with a clever solution, I'll post it here. Thank you for your help. Re Dennis

Comment: It sounds like the Merge in the Edit Queries window would be the ideal solution.  Can you explain/show why you dont have a "common row identifier"?